# cant read result decimal result (Visual Basic 6.0)

Tags: vb6

I have a problem here that my program cant read 0.0## result
if i put value of mid(z) = 0.6875 to this formula

formula = 2.718281828 ^ mid(z) - 2
why the result is -1.12625 ? which it should be -0.0112625

[image: problem at collumn 3 rol 4 & 5]

[source Code 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLYu8.png)
[source code 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBFG5.png)

not only for 0.6875 but also the other numbers that the result is 0.0####
it mean my program cant read 0.0

please help me, sorry for the bad english

i use programming language vb6 btw

Source Code :

```
Dim tengah(11) As Variant

Dim f(11) As Variant

Dim rumus As Variant

Dim x As Variant

Dim a As Variant

Dim b As Variant

Dim fc(11) As Variant

    Private Sub cmdHitung_Click()

    a = txtKiri.Text

    b = txtKanan.Text

    f(a) = 2.718281828 ^ Val(txtKiri.Text) - 2

    f(b) = 2.718281828 ^ Val(txtKanan.Text) - 2

For z = 1 To cboJumlah.Text

    tengah(z) = (a + b) / 2

    f(tengah(z)) = 2.718281828 ^ tengah(z) - 2

    fc(z) = f(tengah(z))

If f(tengah(z)) * f(a) <= 0 Then

     b = a

     a = tengah(z)

  Else

     a = b

     b = tengah(z)

  End If

 Next z

 For x = 1 To cboJumlah

    txtc(x) = tengah(x)

    txtfc(x) = fc(x)

    txtc(x).Visible = True

    txtfc(x).Visible = True

    Text(x).Visible = True

Next x

Private Sub Form_Load()

For a = 1 To 10

     cboJumlah.AddItem (a)

Next a

End Sub

End Sub
```

[Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Thw7W.png)

Comment: how to put Rar file at here, sorry im newbie

Comment: i have upload the image, the issue is my program didnt read the 0,0### number, example if the result should be 0.0112625 but in text box it show 1.12625 

i think there must be validation on it

Comment: check my edited post mate, i have added the image of my source code

Comment: Okay , i just edited it

Comment: The code in the image and code in the post seem to be different? I'm sure people can help you but if you clean up the question details it will make it more likely.

Comment: Can you give an example of z and then show what the expected and actual values are?

Comment: @DaveInCaz Hello thanks for reply , i have found the real issue 
that my program cutshort the zero .

 for the example -0.01126253### but the program write -1,12625306486014 x 10^-2 in text box

do you know how to validate the program to not do cutshort the zero?

look the picture for the detail 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Thw7W.png

Comment: The values are the same, but internally the number is stored in scientific notation.  If you want it shown in your desired format, you'd need to use "Print Using" or "Format$(...)" with the print mask "0.############" (as many places as you need.  Check the help files for the syntax on whichever method you decide upon.

Comment: @BillHileman yeah the values are same, Could you give me the example to use the format / mask ? Sorry im new in programming

Comment: The Issue is Resolved, I tried this Code ' Text1.Text = Format(Text1.Text, "0.########") ' and Its Working

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [VBA Format function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/format-function-visual-basic-for-applications) for a detailed explanation of how to format numbers, dates, etc.

An example of formatting the numbers you use in a standard way would be:

```
For x = 1 To cboJumlah

    txtc(x) = Format(tengah(x), "0.########")
    txtfc(x) = Format(fc(x), "0.########")
    txtc(x).Visible = True
    txtfc(x).Visible = True
    Text(x).Visible = True

Next x
```

If you explore the linked page, you'll see you can even provide custom masks for multiple cases, i.e. one mask for positive, one for null, one for negatives, etc.